# What My Mistake array just show index Zero in C# WEB?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help me why array always show 0 , see what was me make mistaked with my coding

> > http://pastebin.com/Ha8xw2Uh

```
<script runat="server">

void proses(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int list ;
        int list2 ;
        int row = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text) ;
        int column = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox2.Text) ;
        int [,] kalias = new int[row,column];
        for (list = 0 ; list <= row -1 ; list ++)
        {           
            for (list2 = 0 ; list2 <= column -1 ; list2++)
             {  
                 int count = kalias[list,list2] * kalias[list,list2]  ;
                 ListBox1.Items.Add(list.ToString() +"x"+ list2.ToString()+ "="+ count.ToString());         
             }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `kalias` “always show 0” because you **never assign anything to it**.

```
int [,] kalias = new int[row,column];
```

This creates the array and fills it with zeroes. The next time you use it is:

```
    int count = kalias[list,list2] * kalias[list,list2]  ;
```

You have never put anything into `kalias[list,list2]` so of course it will still have zero.

Comment: so how to resolv it . .

Comment: Assign something to it. You are pointing at a blank piece of paper and complaining “there's nothing written on this paper!”